# GraphQL ObjectType with Array field returning null

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql, graphql-ruby

I have a field that is an array that I want to define in my resolver.
The problem is, my result does not return the field which is an array, and just an object with null values.

```
  field :pies do 
    type types[Types::OutputType]
    resolve -> (_obj, _args, ctx){
      pies = []
      CookBook.pages.each do |page|
        labels = []
        labels << OpenStruct.new(
          id: 1,
          name: "blueberry"
        )
        pie = OpenStruct.new(
          id: 1,
          labels: labels
        )
        pies << pie
      end
      pies
    }
  end
```

```
Types::OutputType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
    name 'OutputType'

    field :id, types.ID
    field :labels, types[Types::LabelType]
end
```

```
Types::LabelType = GraphQL::ObjectType.define do
    name 'LabelType'
    field :id, types.ID!
    field :name, types.String
end
```

This is the query:

```
# Write your query or mutation here
{
  pies{
    id,
    labels{
        name
    }
  }
}
```

This is the result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "pies": [
      {
        "id": "9",
        "labels": {
          "name": null
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "labels": {
          "name": null
        }
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

Why is my labels field not returning an array and just returning the object with nulls?

Comment: Try to run this code with changed line defines labels attribute this way: `field :labels, types.fetch[Types::LabelType]` (I suppose `LabelType` is just not loaded into memory at this point, so maybe explicit require is needed).

Comment: @ka8725 Thanks, but I get a undefined method 'fetch' if I do that.